# search multiple text in a folder containing multiple XML file

Tags: linux, putty

I want to search multiple strings (present in text file available in path C:/doc/str.txt) on a folder (name as Sam) containing 500 XML file. The XML is available in same path (C:/doc/Sam/*.xml).

I have also created two folder as 'correct' and 'Incorrect').

If any of the strings are matching with the text available in xml file, then those XML file will be directly copied into "correct folder". If not matching, then it should copy to "Incorrect folder".

Answer (score 1):

Copy your directory structure to a "U&L" host (or use WSL) and run the following commands:

```
cd /path/to/xmlfolder
for file in grep --files-with-matches --file=str.txt *.xml; do
    mv "$file" correct/
done
mv *xml Incorrect/
```